# Getting articles by phrase and tags

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I'm working on search for my blog. Anyway, I'm having some problems with implementing it.

I'm having two models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()

class Tag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Actual search has two fields: phrase and tags. Phrase should look in `Article.title` and `Article.content`, but tag should look for articles that have `Tag` object by `Tag.content`.

I'm having a test too!

```
def test_by_phrase_and_tags(self):
    article_content = "spam"
    tag_content1 = "eggs"
    tag_content2 = "cheese"
    article1 = test_utilities.create_article(content=article_content)
    article2 = test_utilities.create_article(content=article_content)
    test_utilities.create_tag(article1, content=tag_content1)
    test_utilities.create_tag(article2, content=tag_content1)
    test_utilities.create_tag(article2, content=tag_content2)
    response = self.client.get(reverse("blog_search"), {
        "phrase": article_content,
        "tags": "{}, {}".format(tag_content1, tag_content2)
    })
    found_articles = response.context[-1]["found_articles"]
    self.assertEqual(found_articles, [article2])
```

It creates two articles with equal content, equal tag that's set for both articles and unique tag that's set only for 2nd article.

Then I request articles that have the content (both articles should match) and both tags (only 2nd article should match). Overall, I'm asserting that only 2nd article is returned.

I have tried a lot of things with raw SQL and Django ORM, but none seems to work.

With a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_article
WHERE blog_article.content = "spam"
AND blog_article.id IN (
    SELECT blog_tag.article_id FROM blog_tag
    WHERE blog_tag.content = "eggs"
    OR blog_tag.content = "cheese"
);
```

With a join:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_article
JOIN blog_tag
ON blog_article.id = blog_tag.article_id
WHERE blog_article.content = "spam"
AND blog_tag.content = "eggs"
AND blog_tag.content = "cheese";
```

The same and other things with ORM...

So how can I get articles that have `spam` in title or content **and** have tags? I'm stumped.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using raw SQL rather than a pre-existing approach such as [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) with a [Whoosh](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/) back end? I'm using that successfully and it took very little setup.

Comment: @GarryCairns haystack is good, but for simple searching of articles within title and content this is just extra what you are suggesting here.

Comment: There are no reason why I'm not using ready solutions. My only real criteria is that don't want to setup extra servers or things. I'm going to look at your solution. Haystack already looks promising! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to filter the articles by `article.title` or `article.content` with the phrase or with tags:

First define a `related_name` for article in tags model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='tags')
```

Now query:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# supposed input
phrase = 'my search string'
tags = ['tag1', 'tag2']

articles = Article.objects.filter(
   Q(title__icontains=phrase) |
   Q(content__icontains=phrase)) \
   .filter(tags__content__in=tags) \
   .annotate(num_tags=Count('tags')) \
   .filter(num_tags=len(tags))
```

Comment: Almost! Articles that contain phrase in `title` _or_ `content` **and** have tags.

Comment: Please test my answer and then let me know. I hope this is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not. You see, I need to select articles that have title or content like phrase (your code does it) **and** have both of the tags.

Comment: I have made [this](http://vpaste.net/jyNZC), that's the closest I have get so far with using ORM. Sadly, it returns none results.

Comment: Just tested and it works! Thanks! Can you take a look at my code and see why it doesn't work? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then you are looking for those articles that has both tags `eggs` adn `cheese` not one of them, then you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog_article a
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT article_id
   FROM blog_tag
   WHERE content IN ('eggs', 'cheese')
   GROUP BY article_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT content) = 2
) b ON a.id = b.article_id
WHERE a.content = 'spam';
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79853/7)

The idea behind this query is, what they called the [*Relational Division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), and one way to do so is what the subquery does:

```
   SELECT article_id
   FROM blog_tag
   WHERE content IN ('eggs', 'cheese')
   GROUP BY article_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT content) = 2
```

Which is the:

```
   GROUP BY article_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT content) = 2
```

This will ensure that each grouped `article_id`, have both the tags, if the article have one of them then the `COUNT(DISTINCT content)` = 1 and this will be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What does `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT article_id) = 2` line do?

Comment: @daGrevis - I fixed my query, it wasn't work the way I expected. Try it now, it will work fine. The line `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT article_id) = 2` will ensure that each `article_id` has both the `content`s `'cheese', 'eggs'`. If the article_id has one of them not both then this `COUNT(DISTSINCT article_id)` will be = 1 and this article_id will be eliminated.

Comment: This is a really cool query, and applicable to way more than this post. +1

Comment: This is really cool! And it even works! So the next thing is to convert this to ORM code....

Comment: @daGrevis - Yes, you are right. Sorry, I don't know about the ORM and the way you are using sql, but you want to do this in the ORM way. Or, it should be some other way to execute this sql directly as it is in your ORM.

Comment: I could leave it as raw SQL, but it's considered bad practice and may not work for all SQL backends. Is it ANSI SQL?